# After Game Over how to stop score from increasing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

Im making a endless runner game and am using a 'ScoreManager' object with a box collider 2d set to 'is trigger' increasing the score every time a object hits it. But I want it to stop increasing the score if the health reaches 0. This is the ScoreManager code:

```
 public int score;
public Text scoreDisplay;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Obstacle"))
    {
        score++;
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    scoreDisplay.text = score.ToString();

}
```

I would like to add a:

```
public int health = 3;
```

and in the Update function:

```
if (health <= 0) {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

The health is displayed in a player script.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
private Vector2 targetPos;
public float Yincrement;

public float speed;
public float maxHeight;
public float minHeight;

public Text healthDisplay;

public GameObject gameOver;

public int health = 3;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
private void Update()
{
    healthDisplay.text = health.ToString();

    if (health <= 0) {
        gameOver.SetActive(true);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `if (other.CompareTag("Obstacle") && currentHealth > 0) { score++; }` ?

Comment: well when do you change `health`? I would not do these things in `Update` but rather event based e.g. in properties. Also e.g. `scoreDisplay.text = score.ToString();` is enough if it happens in the moment where `score` is actually changed

Comment: In the scoreManager script 'private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Destroy(this);
        }
    }'  seems to work. But it only removes the gameobject after a key is pressed. I've changed that to (health <= 0), but now I need to reference the health variable in the Player script.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever your `health` is defined, substitute it by a property that launches an event whenever set to a value < 0. Like this:

```
public class Player : MonoBehavior
{
    public delegate void PlayerDiedDelegate();
    public static event PlayerDiedDelegate onPlayerDied;

    private int _health;
    public int health
    {
        get
        {
            return _health;
        }
        set
        {
            _health = value;
            if(_health < 0)
            {
                onPlayerDied?.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can attach any controller in your scene to the event:

```
public class ScoreController : MonoBehavior
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        Player.onPlayerDied += OnPlayerDied;
    }

    private void OnPlayerDied()
    {
        // Put your logic here: stop collecting score etc.
    }
}
```